# Alternative data structure for a multidimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, performance, 2d

I have a quick question, I am working a project that requires an object that has an id and a x, y coordinate. This is all stored into an object and the idea is that it is placed into a 2D array. However there is a possibility of a great number of objects created and stored as well size of the array  might be large. Is there something that is more efficient in size and speed in which the data can be stored? I read about using a map might this be my best option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer depends on what your application's primary access pattern is.

If the primary access pattern is looking up the object at a particular x,y coordinate, then you are probably best served by one of the following:

- a 2D array (as you currently have); i.e. `Thing[][]`,
- a `Map<Point, Thing>`, or
- a `Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Thing>>`.

(I suggest the 3rd option, because the second option is liable to result in creation of a temporary `Point` object each time you do a lookup on the data structure.  There are other ways to deal with this, but it makes the application more complicated.)

If the 2D array is sparsely populated, then the Map approaches will save space at the cost of time.  If the array is densely populated then the Map approaches are liable to use *more* space than a 2D array.

If the primary access pattern is to look for objects near a given x,y coordinate (or in a region) then you probably need something like a quad-tree data structure.

One final thing to note is that there are unavoidable overheads in using the standard collection types, especially when one or more of the parameter types is a primitive type.
If you performance requirements are particularly "hard", then designing and implementing a custom data structure by hand will save space and time ... if you do it right.  But the downsides are that you have significantly more code to write, test and maintain, and that a custom data structure won't be compatible with the standard collection APIs.

Comment: The primary access pattern will be the x, y coordinate. In need a balance between speed and space. Currently I did a test with a large amount of data which is a good possibility of happening. Using a 2D array I had to increase the Java heap size and it takes about 6 minutes to read in so I'll look at both map and quad-tree.

Comment: @Stephen, I mostly agree. But using Integers will still create new Integers if the indexes are higher than 128. And then you are creating 2 new objects instead of 1 new Point object. Anyway, Java GC has heavy optimizations for very short lived objects like a Pint key would be in this case. So probably the choice between option 2 or option 3 is mostly preference.

Answer (score 2):

```
Map<Double, java.awt.Point>
```

The java.awt.Point will work, or you could make your own data type to hold the x, y co-ordinate.

This will give you fast lookups but use more memory than a straight array (not sure how much more, probably not anything too bad).

Another alternative is something tha combines the three things (ID, x, y) and stores them in an array and then uses [Arrays.binarySearch](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28T%5B%5D,%20T,%20java.util.Comparator%29) to get at them.  It would require that the array be sorted.

Edit:

If you want to map from the x, y to the double you would do:

```
Map<java.awt.Point, Double>
```

Comment: The id would be of type double. The id would be 1 to the number of "cells" in the 2d array. I mostly be searching the x and y numbers and some what less the id, so I don't know if I can use binary Search. Thanks I check into using a map.

Comment: I think the Map type is wrong.  The OP meeds to map from coordinates to `Double` (or `String`) not the other way around.

Comment: Thinking on it, I don't think putting Double as the key will work given the nature of floating point... right?